# Unable to connect to DB using SQL developer and getting below error "sun.security.validator.ValidatorException" and "Vendor code 17002"

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

While trying to connect to a DB with SQL developer got below error and not allowing it to connect from it. the same details are accessible from all other means like Python or java connections

> An error was encountered performing the requested operation:

IO Error: IO Error sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target, connect lapse 1961 ms., Authentication lapse 0 ms.

Vendor code 17002

Comment: I have usually seen this as a firewall issue

Comment: The error text appears to indicate some kind of certificate issue. Can you edit your question and make it clear: connections from Python and Java work _on the same box_ but SQL Developer doesn't?

Comment: The same issue when connection from Spring Boot (2.6.3) to MS SQL (version=15.0.4198.2) on Docker (engine version: 20.10.8) on MacOS using JDBC com.microsoft.sqlserver driver (version: 10.2.0.jre11) and openjdk version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20.

Any idea how to obtain certificate from this MYSQL instance (where are located on Docker container) ?

Answer (score 1):

The same issue when connection from Spring Boot (`2.6.3`) to MS SQL (version=`15.0.4198.2`) on Docker (engine version: `20.10.8`) on MacOS using JDBC `com.microsoft.sqlserver` driver (version: `10.2.0.jre11`) and openjdk version `"11.0.12" 2021-07-20`.

In my case solution is to use jdbc driver in version: `9.4.1.jre11`
(version `10.2.0.jre11` is not working)